# How can we search in dom for a text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<div id='imgBody'>` and that has an image tag and it's src is `src="a1.jpg"`. I have another div and inside of it I have ul tag and many li's inside of it, and image tags inside of each li. One of those image tags also has `src="a1.jpg"`. I have src of main div in a variable and I want to search the image which has that src inside li's and I want to get the index of found image tag's parent li.

How can I achieve this?

**HTML**

```
<div id='imgBody'><img src="img/a1.jpg"></div>

<div id='main'> 
<ul class="ulthumbs">
   <li class="thumbImg" data-rel="a0">
    <img src="img/a0.jpg" width='150' height="80">
   </li>
   <li class="thumbImg" data-rel="a1">
    <img src="img/a1.jpg" width='150' height="80">
   </li>
   <li class="thumbImg" data-rel="a2">
   <img src="img/a2.jpg" width='150' height="80">
   </li>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var getImgTag = $('#imgBody').children().attr('src');
var findIndex  = find(getImgTag).index();
console.log(findIndex);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the LI that contains an image with the same source

```js
var getImgTag = $('#imgBody img').attr('src');
var findIndex = $('li:has(img[src="' + getImgTag + '"])').index();

console.log('The index is : ' + findIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='imgBody'>
  <img src="img/a1.jpg">
</div>

<div id='main'>
  <ul class="ulthumbs">
    <li class="thumbImg" data-rel="a0">
      <img src="img/a0.jpg" width='150' height="80">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbImg" data-rel="a1">
      <img src="img/a1.jpg" width='150' height="80">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbImg" data-rel="a2">
      <img src="img/a2.jpg" width='150' height="80">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is super cool, thanks, one more question if I don't know where is that src located I mean I dont know if it's in li or in any div or anywhere how to find then.

Comment: basically I am thinking of the way we search on any document like ctrl+f any we type text to find, is there any way that we search in dom like this?

Comment: You can't really search like that, but you could do `$('img[src="' + getImgTag + '"]')` to just find the image, but that would match the other image as well, as it has the same source, that's why I specifically targeted the image inside the LI

Comment: can I have your personal email or skype